# Access Spring Service name in the service itself

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations

I am having some difficulties to do something I thought would be easy.
I have a service:

```
@Service("tr_v1_mapper")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class VoneMapper implements GenericMapper{
// Mapping code ...

// Service name
  String serviceName = "tr_v1_mapper"
}
```

Basically, I want to stock my service name in a String variable inside my class VoneMapper without harcoding it.
is it something possible ?
Thanks by advance for your help.

PM

Comment: This sounds very much like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What use do you think having the service name will be?

Answer (score 4):

What about using a constant in the annotation? More info here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-annotation-attribute-value-restrictions

```
@Service(VoneMapper.SERVICE_NAME)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class VoneMapper implements GenericMapper {
// Mapping code ...

    // Service name
    static final String SERVICE_NAME = "tr_v1_mapper";
}
```